# Can We Use Splash in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I Got the Manual way of importing in the android module and IOS module **But I want to use it using the JSX tags or using ImageBackground Tag in the .js file.**

Can anyone help me sending an sample code for the splash screen using JSX Tags.

Answer (score 1):

React Native within the `create-react-native-app` (CRNA) has a splash screen under:

`react-native-project
    - assets
        - icon.png
        - splash.png`

You would just edit the splash.png and that's what will be shown, however if you have an authentication flow or a system that requires loading and you need to show a sort of loading screen (this can also be a splash screen). Then this guide at `react-navigation` will be helpful: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html

The `AuthLoadingScreen` component will basically be your splash component, enter whatever logic you want there, you can even customise the `View` component within to be an image, etc.

Comment: OK Thank You for the Help... :-)